# Can adult citizens carry knives in a school zone in NH

Tags: weapons, school, new-hampshire

My understanding is that there is no federal legal distinction between concealed and open carry of knives. Also, NH doesn't prohibit the carry of knives for most people. Some felons are prohibited.

Can most adults in NH carry knives in cars while driving through a school zone? Can most pedestrians in NH carry a knife on a sidewalk through a school zone?

Comment: I added the tag [tag:new-hampshire].  In the future, please use appropriate jurisdiction tags on all your questions.